# Easily scripted audio splitter

Tags: windows, gratis, audio, mp3, scripting

I would like to split up my downloaded podcasts (.mp3 files) into 5 minute segments,  audio normalize them, and script this to occur whenever a USB is plugged in. I would like to do this with the minimum of hassle, as i don't know scripting.

Requirements:

- free
- runs on Windows 10

Some podcatchers do provide audio normalization but as far as I can tell, not scripting support.

Comment: Some audio editors provide scripts or chains within the user interface, such as Audacity. Also get down with the hoi polloi and change [gratis] to [free], which is more searchable. To the meta!

Answer (score 1):

[mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php) lets you do the splitting, but it misses audio normalization or scripting. There are plenty of other tools you can use for that.

You can manually indicate where to split, have it split automatically on silence, or every x minutes.

Quoting the features list:

> - split mp3, ogg vorbis and native FLAC files from a begin time to an end time without decoding
> - recursive multiple files split
> - ID3v1 & ID3v2 tags support for mp3 files (using libid3tag), vorbis comments support
> - split an album with splitpoints from the freedb.org server
> - split an album with local .XMCD, .CDDB or .CUE file
> - audacity labels file support
> - split automatically with silence detection
> - trim using silence detection
> - split by a fixed time length
> - split in equal time tracks
> - split files created with Mp3Wrap or AlbumWrap
> - split concatenated mp3 files
> - support for mp3 VBR (variable bit rate)
> - specify output directory for split files

Quoting from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp3splt):

> Mp3Splt is a command line utility, but the Mp3splt project has also created a graphical user interface, called Mp3splt-gtk, and a library, called Libmp3splt.

`Mp3splt-gtk` is available from that same SourceForge page.

I'm not sure about the Win10 requirement, but given the nature of the program and the fact that it runs under my Win7, I don't expect problems.

Comment: @ErljaJkdf. If you really want to script it, [here are at least 2 methods](http://superuser.com/a/964044/50173)

Comment: I'll have to use Autohotkey as well right? I want it to detect the download and run the split, no clicks required.

Comment: @Erlja. No, not normalization (updated my answer). "Detect download" is not in your question.